# Rails 3 Routes: Default format and also limited formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, format

I am having a problem combining 2 rails routing features (default params and param matching). Each is independently easy enough to solve, but when combined, the results are not quite what I am after.

**The Rule:**

```
get "/foobars(.:format)" => "foobars#index", :defaults => {:format => :json}, :format => /(xml|json)/
```

**What I want:**

1. `format` param is optional
2. if no `format` is included, default the format to `json`
3. if `format` is included, ensure it is only `xml` or `json`
4. if an unsupported `format` is passed, such as `html`, this route rule should not match.

**What I am getting:**

1. `format` param is optional
2. if no `format` is included, default the format to `json`
3. if `format` is included, ensure it is only `xml` or `json`
4. if an unsupported `format` is passed, such as `baz`, this route rule matches and sets the format to `JSON`.

The difference in point `#4` is what I am trying to solve. In other words, I am after this:

```
GET /foobars      => "foobars#index"  with format `json`
GET /foobars.json => "foobars#index"  with format `json`
GET /foobars.xml  => "foobars#index"  with format `xml`
GET /foobars.baz  => "something#else" handled by another route rule lower down
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried making the last section a constraint?

```
get "/foobars(.:format)" => "foobars#index", :defaults => {:format => :json}, :constraints => {:format => /(xml|json)/}
```

Comment: I tried this a long time ago and it didn't work, but I must have had something misconfigured then because all tests pass now. Thanks.